# Excel Sheet Index Identify by Unique Number in a VBA Macro?

Tags: excel, vba

Two working macro’s for Checklists & Templates below

Workbook = Steve
Sheet within workbook has been allocated 15286

I need to add sheets to a macro and need to know how to locate what I assume is a unique _number, so that I can perform the same routine on a new data sheet within Same workbook

The workbook contains the same macro, several times the only difference being a number

Eg: Checklists =

```
Sub PublishChecklists()
'
' Saves htm version of Sheet on Server
'
Range("M8:M2000").Select
Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 0
Selection.autofilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array("<>Exc")
Columns("A:J").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects("Steve_**15826**")
.Title = "CHECKLIST LIST"
.Filename = "\\f:\data\Work\Checklists.htm"
.Publish (True)
.AutoRepublish = False
End With
ChDir "F:\data\Work\Today's Work"
Columns("A:J").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Selection.autofilter Field:=7
Columns("H:H").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("L8").Select

End Sub
```

Templates =

```
Sub PublishTemplates()
'
' Saves htm version of Sheet on Server
'
Range("M8:M2000").Select
Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 0
Selection.autofilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array("<>Exc")
Columns("A:J").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects("Steve_**3496**")
.Title = "TEMPLATES LIST"
.Filename = "\\f:\data\Work\Templates.htm"
.Publish (True)
.AutoRepublish = False
End With
ChDir "F:\data\Work\Today's Work"
Columns("A:J").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Selection.autofilter Field:=7
Columns("H:H").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("L8").Select

End Sub
```

--

Both work, the only thing that appears different is the "15286" & "3486", as they are different sheets?
if I add a new sheet, I need to know, how I can locate the "3486" number bit as it will be a different number for a new sheet

I inherited the code and have no idea how the  were found in order for them to be placed in the above code

Many thanks for your time

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Just call the same procedure and pass the number to it as an argument.

Your procedure would be similar to:

```
Sub PublishLists(RefNumber As Long, Title As String)

'...
'...
'...
        With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects("Steve_**" & RefNumber & "**")
            .Title = Title & " LIST"

'...
'...
'...

End Sub
```

You'd then call the procedure and pass the number and title to it:

```
Sub Test()

    PublishLists 15826, "CHECKLIST"
    PublishLists 3496, "TEMPLATES"

End Sub
```

**Edit:**
I haven't tested any of your code - have just adjusted to accept passed arguments and remove anything that says `Select` or `Selection`.
The `Test` procedure here would execute `PublishLists` twice using different arguments each time.

```
Public Sub Test()

    'The three values are passed to the "PublishLists" procedure.
    'First line would PublishObjects to "Steve_**15826**" and second to "Steve_**3496**"

    PublishLists 15826, "CHECKLIST ", "Checklists.htm"
    PublishLists 3496, "TEMPLATES", "Templates.htm"

End Sub

Sub PublishLists(RefNumber As Long, Title As String, SaveFile As String)

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Update sheet name as required.
        With .Range("M8:M2000")
            .Font.ColorIndex = 0
            .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array("<>Exc")
        End With
        .Columns("A:J").Hidden = True
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.PublishObjects("Steve_**" & RefNumber & "**") 'RefNumber variable passed to name.
        .Title = Title & " LIST" 'Title variable passed to title.
        .Filename = "\\f:\data\Work\" & SaveFile 'SaveFile variable passed to FileName
        .Publish (True)
        .AutoRepublish = False
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Update sheet name as required.
        With .Columns("A:J")
            .Hidden = False
            .AutoFilter Field:=7
        End With
        .Columns("H:H").Hidden = True
        .Range("L8").Select 'The only cell that is selected.
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, not sure that really answers my question though :-) - how is ANY sheet allocated a number and HOW can I find out what that new sheets number would be, the numbers 3496 & 15826 are already in the code.  If I create a new sheet, how can I find out what number (as above would be.  I'm assuming 15826 & 3496 are generated from SOMEWHERE as the seem to be very specific.  I hope that makes sense. as this seems to be a very difficult question for people to grasp.

Comment: I'll update my code to show how it would work in the context of your code.  I doubt anyone can answer where the numbers come from - it's not Excel that creates those numbers.  They must have been either manually assigned, or the pattern has been coded into VBA/some other package to create them.

Comment: Just need to reiterate - _I'm assuming 15826 & 3496 are generated from SOMEWHERE_ - they will be, but not automatically by Excel.  These numbers are generated by something _your_ system is using.

Comment: Thanks Darren, All I can add is the resulting htm file is hosted on SharePoint 2010 server if that's any help.  Although it doesn't help that much it IS good to know there's a somewhat random element to this